# Powershell - if statement operator through paramenter

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variables, parameters, operators

Hello Powershell expert,
i have a short question regarding a powershell issue of mine.

I try to pass parameter variables to process these variables in an if statement.My Goal is to have a fully dynamic if statement.
Let me show you the circumstance:

```
function Get-Test {

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varA,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varB,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$op
     )
     $statement = "$varA $op $varB"

     if ($statement) {
        Write-Host "One"

     } else {
        Write-Host "Two"
     }

}

Get-Test -varA "Test1" -varB "Test1" -op "-ne"
```

Explanation:
No matter what i put in as the paramter $op it is always gonna get to "One"

So my questions is: Is there any possibillity to use parameters/varibales to have a sort of dynamic operator in my if statement ?

Comment: `$statement = IEX "'$varA' $op '$varB'"` should work but there is most likely a better way to approach this if you explain what your final goal is

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I expect you know this already, but for the OP's benefit if ```$op = "; Format-Volume -DriveLetter C ;"``` it's going to give some very unexpected results :-).

Comment: @mclayton im with you here you know it but sometimes people dont want to listen :)

Comment: Thank you very much @SantiagoSquarzon ! The idea with Invoke-Expression was great. Works like a charme in my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @SantiagoSquarzon's comments, one way to do this is to use [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2) to generate a string containing a PowerShell command, and then execute it:

```
function Get-Test {

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varA,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varB,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$op
     )

     $statement = IEX "'$varA' $op '$varB'"

     if ($statement) {
        Write-Host "One"

     } else {
        Write-Host "Two"
     }

}

Get-Test -varA "Test1" -varB "Test1" -op "-ne"
```

However, you should be very careful to validate your input (especially if it's an "untrusted" source like a user interface) as it contains the same type of problem as a SQL Injection Attack - that is, you could end up running arbitrary code inside your function.

For example if `$op` somehow ends up with the value `"; write-host 'i didn''t mean to run this' ;"` (e.g. from unsanitised user input or a spiked input file) your function will execute the `write-host` command *without any errors* so your output will look like this:

```
i didn't mean to run this
One
```

That might not be so bad in itself, but what if there was something more malicious in the string - e.g. `"; Format-Volume -DriveLetter C ;"` - do you *really* want to be executing that command on your server?

One way to address this is to have a list of known operations you'll support - it's a bit more work up front, but it'll avoid the security issue with `Invoke-Expression`:

```
function Get-Test {

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varA,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varB,
         [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$op
    )

    $result = switch( $op )
    {
        "-eq" { $varA -eq $varB }
        "-lt" { $varA -lt $varB }
        "-gt" { $varA -gt $varB }
        # etc for any other operations you want to support
        default {
            throw "invalid operation '$op'"
        }
    }

    if ($result) {
        Write-Host "One"

    } else {
       Write-Host "Two"
    }

}
```

If you try that with an invalid operation you'll get something like this:

```
PS> Get-Test -varA "Test1" -varB "Test1" -op "; write-host 'i didn't mean to run this' ;"
Exception:
Line |
  19 |              throw "invalid operation '$op"
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | invalid operation '; write-host 'i didn't mean to run this' ;
```

Comment: Nicely done. While it's more cumbersome to enumerate operators (and, hypothetically, more could be introduced later), it allows you to limit allowable operators to those that make sense, namely _binary_ ones.

Comment: Also thank you mclayton and mklement0 for your very helpful answers !
I think this is gpoing to be the way to go for me !

Answer (score 3):

As for what you tried:

- Your function makes no attempt to *evaluate* the value of expandable string `"$varA $op $varB"` *as code*.
- Given that *any non-empty string* in PowerShell is considered `$true` in a Boolean context, `if ($statement)` is therefore *always* true.

---

While **[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression)** allows you to evaluate a string as PowerShell code, it comes with important **caveats**:

- In general, it **makes your code vulnerable to injection of unwanted commands** (see [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)'s comment on the question for an example).

  - In short: Only ever use `Invoke-Expression` if you either *fully control* the input string or *implicitly trust* one that you have been given. **Typically, superior and safer alternatives to `Invoke-Expressions` are available**, as in this case: see the solution below, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) for background information.
- In your case specifically, embedding `$varA` and `$varB` as-is inside an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) means that evaluation via `Invoke-Expression` would fail for *string* parameter values and, generally, for values of .NET types that do not have *meaningful string representations*.

---

Therefore, do the following:

- **To prevent code injection, use PowerShell's language parser to examine `$op` to ensure that it truly represents a PowerShell *operator***.

  - Alternatively:

    - Use *regex matching* to ensure that `$op` represents a (potential) operator, such as `$op -match '^(-[a-z]{2,}|[-+*/%])$'`
    - Match against an explicit set of allowable operators, as shown in [mclayton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73025267/45375).
  - Note: The solution below uses [`System.Management.Automation.PSParser.Tokenize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSParser.Tokenize), which only tells you whether a token represents an operator *in the abstract*, irrespective of category (comparison, logical, ...), arity (unary, binary, ternary), or syntax form (`-`-prefixed or symbol-based, such as `+`). As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you can use [`System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser.ParseInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser.ParseInput) instead, which provides more detailed operator information, but requires more effort; e.g., the following determines whether `$op` represents a *binary* operator, irrespective of category; if you wanted to limit operators to binary *comparison* operators, use `'BinaryPrecedenceComparison'` instead; see the [`System.Management.Automation.Language.TokenKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.TokenKind) enumeration:

    ```bash
    $op = '-ne'      # sample input
    $tokens = $null
    # Note: '-not' is a dummy operator that forces $op to be parsed in expression mode.
    $null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(
      "-not $op",
      [ref] $tokens, 
      [ref] $null
    )
    # Exactly 3 tokens are expected: 
    # 1 for (dummy token) -not, one for $op, and the EndOfInput token.
    [bool] ($tokens.Count -eq 3 -and ($tokens[1].TokenFlags -band 'BinaryOperator'))
    ```
- **Instead of using `Invoke-Expression`, construct a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)** from an expandable string, and pass `$varA` and `$varB` *as arguments* to that script block, which ensures that their values are used as-is (rather than undergoing *stringification*).

**Solution**:

```bash
function Get-Test {

  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varA,
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$varB,
    [parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$op
  )

  # IMPORTANT: To prevent code injection, ensure that $op really refers to
  #            a PowerShell operator.
  # Note: '-not' is a dummy operator that forces $op to be parsed in expression mode.
  $tokenKind = (
    [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize("-not $op", [ref] $null) |
      Select-Object -Skip 1
  ).Type

  if ('Operator' -ne $tokenKind) {
    Throw "'$op' is not a PowerShell operator; it is a token of type $tokenKind"
  }

  # Create a script block based on the operator, and pass the operands (parameters)
  # *as arguments* to the script block.
  & ([scriptblock]::Create("`$args[0] $op `$args[1]")) $varA $varB

}
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to work out how to mitigate specially crafted values of ```$varA``` and ```$varB``` and still keep the ```$op``` dynamic - passing them into a scriptblock does just that :-).

Comment: Thanks, @mclayton. Another problem with "baking" `$varA` and `$varB` into the string passed to `iex` (which your answer no longer does) is that the expanded values are again subject to expansion, e.g. if `$varA` originally contains (unexpanded) `'$HOME'`), and enclosing in embedded `'...'` would convert numbers to strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! Really detailed and useful. I am aware of the injecting risk. But this is kind of a low risk in my special case. But i will implement a validation soultion for the parameter input of $op

Comment: Understood, @LKo.exp. I'm glad to hear the answer helped; my pleasure.